# Can I ask to have another interview with hiring company if they offer me a position?

Tags: interviewing

Long story short, I'm about to find out if I am successful for a job I interviewed at last week.

I had one quick phone interview with the 'people and culture' HR person, who then called me back to arrange an interview.

I had the interview at the company's office. I arrived from the elevator to reception, and then ushered into a meeting room adjacent to the reception area.

The interview went well and I got a good vibe from the people I met with, however I did not get a look at the office or size of the team, the vibe of the place out 'on the floor' so to speak. At the end they said they'd be making a quick decision and would get back to me asap.

I do like to get a sense of the place I'm interviewing at - is it frantic, do people look stressed, unhappy, are they hanging around chatting, that sort of thing. This time I don't feel like I really know what the work environment is like.

If I'm offered the job, is it ok to ask to go back in to meet with them again, because of this reason? Is it ok to say I'd like to ask them more questions so that I can make a decision? I did ask some of these questions relating to what the typical day to day workload/tasks would be, but I worry about accepting the job and ending up working in a place that is understaffed/overworked. It's hard to ask a question in the interview 'how much work do you expect of me / will I be able to go home on time / do you have enough staff to cope with the work you agree to deliver' without shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Don't call it an interview, just call it a meeting or introduction.

Answer (score 3):

Talking to the hiring manager is generally not a problem, just talk/mail the HR that you have certain questions and would like to talk to the hiring manager before making a decision. This should help alleviate some concerns around the work practices etc.

However, Your request to visit the workplace may not be entertained at many companies (Needs security clearance, someone is required to show you around, access can be restricted etc). But it won't hurt to check with the HR if you could informally meet the team before joining it.

Comment: Upvoted for your second paragraph. Because of this, it may be appropriate for the OP to think carefully about what cultural factors are important, and try to determine other ways to get that information without being allowed to walk around the office.